# The Interface of Ubuntu 16 is loading at startup on Ubuntu 20

Tags: boot

I booted my computer today and found Ubuntu 16 and its interface is getting loaded although it displays Ubuntu 20 everywhere. The first login screen is also that of Ubuntu 20. How do I change it back to Ubuntu 20 interface.[image: screenshot]

Extra information:-

history of commands that I ran-
[image: history]

Basically what I did was- install timeshift, create partition table in flash drive, took backup in it, reduced startup applications (only microsoft teams app), upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 and download ampgpu graphics driver. The computer still worked fine after restarting multiple times.
This morning I tried to access the grub menu by pressing shift multiple times. Didn't open GRUB, but I was greeted with this issue.

Comment: I just upgraded from 18.04 to 20.4 yesterday and from 16.04 to 18.04 a year back. It was working fine yesterday even after multiple boot ups. And i didn't add any add ons or customisations.

Comment: Can you tell exactly which config could it be that I messed up?

Comment: I can send you a history of the commands that I ran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the login screen, when the field for typing your password appears, on the lower right corner there is a "Configure" icon. Click it and select "Ubuntu" instead of "Unity" (or whatever is selected). Then login normally.

[Ubuntu Login Screen Session Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16DaU.png)

Comment: Issue resolved. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to reset the desktop to its factory settings. Open Terminal and type this:

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/
```

Be sure to that directly *on* the device, as this will not work correctly if you're SSHing into the machine.

> **Note**: This will reset Gnome to the defaults for Ubuntu 20.04 (or whatever version you're currently running). If you had any modifications to the desktop, you'll need to re-do them.

Comment: too much data..... cant do factory reset.

Comment: Too much data? Your data should be fine if you're just resetting Gnome. This won't reset Ubuntu to zero. If you've made a lot of modifications to the desktop and would like to keep them as much as possible, then you might have to use Gnome Tweak and see whether any of the options available will let you get the 20.04 desktop back without losing all of your desktop customisations.

Comment: gnome tweak? is it a program that I have to install?

Comment: ok I'll check if it can be done.

Comment: Yep. You can find it in the Software Centre. Alternatively, you can install it with a `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`. This will let you modify the themes, fonts, extensions and whatnot. [It's FOSS](https://itsfoss.com/gnome-tweak-tool/) has a short explanation that might be useful.